# OpenCV VideoCapture gives me a gray screen when I'm reading from 3 or more rtsp streams a time

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, rtsp

I'm reading rtsp streams on our LAN network. When it's a single or 2 streams it runs smoothly but as I try it on more than 2 streams it starts giving me a gray screen where few pixels are visble.

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_uri)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE, 2)

fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
delay_after_each_frame = 1/fps
print(delay_after_each_frame)

while True:
    try:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
    except:
        pass

    if self.stopper[camera_id]:
        del self.stopper[camera_id]
        return

    if not ret:
        continue

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(src=frame, code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame = cv2.resize(
        frame,
        (self.config.frame_width, self.config.frame_height)
    )
    queue.enqueue(frame)
    time.sleep(delay_after_each_frame)
```

here I used queue to store frames and this script is running in a thread.

Is there any way by which i read streams from multiple cameras at a time without those gray frames.
This is the frame that i'm getting.

[image: grey background]

code for multiple streams and output.

```py
for camera_id in self.config.get_camera_ids():
    if camera_id not in self.threads:
        self.threads[camera_id] = Thread(
            target=self.process_rtsp_stream,
            args=(self.config.get_rtsp(camera_id),
                    self.queues[camera_id], camera_id)
        )
        self.threads[camera_id].daemon = True
        self.threads[camera_id].start()

# remove thread for deleted cameras
for camera_id in self.threads:
    if camera_id not in self.config.get_camera_ids():
        del self.threads[camera_id]
```

Comment: Please provide your code for multiple streams reading and output frames.

Comment: code provided for reading streams using threads and for output, I'm just running an infinite loop constantly checking the queue and if their is a frame display it.

Comment: It's likely a bandwidth issue. To confirm it and if you have control over the cameras you're trying to get the streams from, try to lower their fps or lower the resolution and check if there are less lost packets.